# Load Test results gives different timing results in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I am running load test with same number of users at different time. But the results were huge time margin difference for each time.

Whether I want to change any settings in visual studio or this issue is due to internet connectivity?

Here the count column is also have different numbers.

Here is my screenshots

[image]
[image]

I am very new to this tool and I searched many sites regarding this but I could not found the solution. Help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: Please copy the text of the two screenshots into the question. It is difficult to see what is common and what changes between two images. Even better, you could combine the two tables so we could easily see the values for each URL in the two runs side by side.

Comment: Timing differences can happen because the computers or networks involved can have other work to do and that workload varies during the day.